# File not being written as per expected while using Mutex Locks in Golang

Tags: go, asynchronous, concurrency, goroutine

So I am writing this program that I want to run concurrently. I have 10 workers that should read an API response from a json file and append the result to another output file. I ran the code synchronously first, which ran as per expectation. Even, I put the working code into a for loop, running 10 times. The output got appended 10 times in the output file.

Now I want to do this asynchronously. To avoid race conditions, I am using mutex locks to lock the output file so that only one thread can access the output file once (doing this mainly because, each time I am overwriting the output).

Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type RapidAPIRealStonksResponse struct {
    Price            float64   `json:"price"`
    ChangePoint      float64   `json:"change_point"`
    ChangePercentage float64   `json:"change_percentage"`
    TotalVolume      string    `json:"total_vol"`
    Timestamp        time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
}

type RapidAPIRealStonks struct {
    URL                string
    ResponseStatusCode int
    Response           RapidAPIRealStonksResponse
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    // Asynchronously running this code
    numWorkers := 10
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numWorkers)
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            worker_action()
        }()
        fmt.Printf("Worker #%d in action\n", i)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    // Synchronously running the code
    // worker_action()

    fmt.Println("Total execution time", time.Since(start))
}

func fetching_data() (RapidAPIRealStonksResponse, error) {
    resBytes, err := os.ReadFile("./sample_api_response.json")
    if err != nil {
        return RapidAPIRealStonksResponse{}, err
    }

    var res RapidAPIRealStonksResponse
    if err = json.Unmarshal(resBytes, &res); err != nil {
        return RapidAPIRealStonksResponse{}, err
    }
    res.Timestamp = time.Now().In(time.UTC)
    return res, nil
}

func storing_data(res RapidAPIRealStonksResponse) error {
    filePath := "./output_json_response.json"
    fileLock := sync.Mutex{}
    fileLock.Lock()
    defer fileLock.Unlock()

    file, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var jsonData []RapidAPIRealStonksResponse
    if len(data) == 0 {
        jsonData = make([]RapidAPIRealStonksResponse, 0)
    } else {
        if err = json.Unmarshal(data, &jsonData); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    updatedData := append(jsonData, res)

    updatedContent, err := json.Marshal(updatedData)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err = file.Truncate(0); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if _, err = file.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if _, err = file.Write(updatedContent); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func worker_action() {
    // Fetching API Response
    res, err := fetching_data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error faced while fetching API Response.", err.Error())
    }

    // Storing the API Response
    err = storing_data(res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error faced while storing API Response.", err.Error())
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be written 10 times (an array having 10 elements), but I am only getting 1 element in the array. What is the mistake I am making here?
I am still learning about mutex locks. Pl point out if there is any mistake in it's implementation.

Sample API response

```json
{
    "price": 216.9,
    "change_point": -0.71,
    "change_percentage": -0.33,
    "total_vol": "151.14M"
}
```

Comment: `fileLock` should be created outside of `storing_data`.

Comment: Yup, this solved the problem. Can you pl elaborate on the reasoning?

Comment: If `fileLock` is created in `storing_data`, every goroutine will get its own new `fileLock`. So `fileLock.Lock()` protects nothing. The key point of a lock is that every one should act on the same lock object. This is not Go specific.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you.